# Circle Division by Lightning Line Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, circles, arithmetic-progressions

I was studying the Circle Division Problem, which is perfectly described with a solution here: [LINK](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyLines.html)

But for now I have quite similar problem, the difference is the cutting line:

[image: LINK TO IMAGE]

So, I was trying to manage to find recurrent formula for this specific problem, but failed. Could anyone give me the hint in what way I should start thinking?

What I managed to find:
1 slice - 2 pieces,
2 slices - 12 pieces,
3 slices - 31 pieces (?)

And when I cut 2nd time so I hit the first line totally 9 times, might this be helpful?

Thank you all for your time and suggestions, I'm still quite a beginner in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so somehow I managed to first find the recurrent formula, which is: $$ f(n) = f(n-1) + 9(n-1) +1$$
Then, based on this formula, I've tried to make sequence: $$ f(n) = f(n-1) +9(n-1)+1=f(n-2)+9(n-2)+9(n-1)+1+1=f(n-3)+9(n-3)+9(n-2)+9(n-1)+1+1+1  = ...=f(1)+1+1+...+1+9((n-1)+(n-2)+...+1)= f(1) + n-1+9(n(n-1)/2) = 2+n-1+(9n^2-9n)/2 = (2+2n+9n^2-9n)/2 = (9n^2-7n+2)/2 $$

Also I've tried to prove this formula with induction and it worked well, just include above mentioned recurrent formula while proving.